# Regression discontinuity design

Tags: regression, applied-econometrics, stata, rdd

I have this setting:

Where V is the running variable and M=1 if V>0. It is a sharp RDD. D is a set of period dummies and $\tau$ is the calendar year. Coefficients in
vector $\beta$ capture the sharp regression discontinuity effects $\tau$ years after. $\delta_\tau$ are calendar years fixed effects.
My question is if someone can help me in setting this multiperiod RDD using the "rdrobust" command in stata.[image]